# Best practice for sorting and being able to "check all" in a table with checkboxes

Tags: forms, interaction-design, tables, visual-cues, signifier

I have a table as part of a form for which users can click the header row to sort by that column (and click again to reverse order). The table also contains checkboxes, and clicking the checkbox in the header row checks or unchecks all checkboxes below.

[image: Table with sorting options and checkboxes]

However, there is also the case that the user may want to order by whether a checkbox is checked or unchecked. What is the best practice to enable this sort while also preserving the ability to check / uncheck all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to sort of the selection, then you should go ahead and **add a label** to the field. Else, you will be breaking your system's consistency.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flse3g.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Check All** / **Select All** button just above or below the table which will enable the user to select all the contents.

The functionality of sorting by date will be kept same as in now. In this way you an achieve both the objectives.

Comment: You misunderstood the question, the problem is with sorting the selection, not sorting by date.